# How to setup Ec2 for MongoDB so that RAM and storage will automatically increase based on their requirement?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I have a MongoDB in AWS Ec2 Instance and want to automatically increase RAM and storage size. I search various documents and blogs, some said, use MongoAtlas or use vertical Ec2 Autoscaling.
But my question is how to setup Ec2 for MongoDB so that RAM and storage will automatically grow based on their requirement?

Please suggest to me, how to handle this?

Does anyone know how to set based on the above requirement?

Comment: There is not such thing on any platform. on EC2 you can write a script that automatically increases storage when it gets to x% but after that it can't "shrink" dynamically. same goes for RAM you choose memory limitations of your machine when you create it.

Answer (score 2):

Neither EC2 nor Atlas have the ability to automatically resize a particular *database instance*.

There is no such thing as "vertical ec2 autoscaling". The autoscaling that ec2 provides is horizontal - it will launch more (identical) machines for you based on defined criteria.

In both ec2 and atlas you can choose the instance size. But an instance won't be resized automatically.

Comment: Setup mongodb instance above the size of your requirement and also use cloud watch to monitor instance.  Use this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html